# Right syntax for SUDO in exec PHP

Tags: php, linux, sudo, rm

I want to use `sudo` Linux command in PHP, with this

```
system("sudo -pMYPASSWORD rm -rf *.png");
```

but I am not succeeding. What is the right syntax for it?

Comment: if you have sudo privileges ... you should use sudoers and not write your password into some script that may be accessed from somewhere ... and someone.

Comment: Even better, fix the permissions of your server so you don't _have to_ use `sudo`.

Comment: The problem is to allow for removing files from a PHP script, and restricting the collaborators (programmers) which are able to to it. Better I create a .sh file in a crontab and let PHP alone?

Comment: For a discussion of this topic, you can look at [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/is-it-safe-to-allow-www-data-to-execute-privileged-commands)